Why props obj still exists in memory after component unmounted?
How could the prop object exist in memory even after component unmounted
const myObj = {....}
<parent>
   <child myObj = {myObj}>
      ...
   </child>
</parent>

Once both parent and child unmounted I still see myObj allocated in memory when I do snapshots comparison in Google Dev Tool...
Also, every time component mounts it allocates more.
So how to properly prevent this kind of memory leak and kill props obj in memory?

Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

You have defined it outside of your component. Why do you expect it to share the same lifecycle?

If you've already done a snapshot, you should see in that very snapshot where the object is still referenced from

@VladDX sorry but I didn't get you. What's exactly wrong with the code

@john-glabb: If you would provide a bit more context, you could avoid confusion. It is not obvious what is "inside" the component. I guess I understand what you mean, but the code that you provided doesn't make sense as it is (Obviously. I know that you know that). I'd suggest to provide a complete component.
